# How do I route to /Configuration/ URL in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

This is for an ASP.NET MVC3 web application. In RegisterRoutes I have the following as my only line:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "Configuration", new { controller = "DeviceConfiguration", action = "Index" });
```

When I run the project, going to the URL /Configuration/ gives me a 404 error.  However if I change the word Configuration to any other word, such as:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "Configuratio", new { controller = "DeviceConfiguration", action = "Index" });
```

Then going to the URL /Configuratio/ loads just fine.  It seems as if ASP.NET is simply refusing to route to the URL /Configuration/.

Again, this is the only line in RegisterRoutes; I've tried commenting out everything else to debug this.  I have no MapRoute or IgnoreRoute calls in my code anywhere else, and I am not editing the routing table in any location.

How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you have a physical folder called `Configuration` under the root of your application. The ASP.NET MVC routing engine has preference for physical folders over routes. One possible way is to set the `RouteExistingFiles` property to true **after** your route definition:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", 
    "Configuration", 
    new { controller = "DeviceConfiguration", action = "Index" 
});
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

Comment: This was indeed the problem, I solved it by moving my Configuration folder into a folder with a different name.  Thanks!